# Exclude result from MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Select query something like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?
```

I need a condition to it which excludes a specific result.
`if(type = 'tv' and that type's code = '123')` 
then exclude that row from select result.
Since my SQL skills are not very strong, I am not sure how to make that happen.

Comment: Could you show your table structure please? You can use sqlfiddle.com to make a reproducible example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE  id = ? AND not(type = 'tv' and code = '123')
```

Is this what you looking for?

There is a difference between 
`type <> 'tv' and code <> '123'`  and   `not(type = 'tv' and code = '123')`

Comment: Well... are you sure? My understanding is the OP want to *exclude* rows having *both* `type = 'tv'` *and* `code = '123'`.

Comment: Not sure :) .. Thats why mentioned the second line with both usage. whichever suits the requirement can be chosen. But from his question what I understand is when and only when both condition matches , it should ignore the record. In that case my first assumption is right

Comment: Here is a sqlfiddle comparing the 3 answers http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dc49/3 That remembers me [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) `not(a and b) ⇔ a or b` :D

Comment: This is that query what I was looking for...I had tried something similar just without the "NOT" value. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     SELECT * FROM table WHERE  id = ? and (type <> 'tv' or code <> 123)
```

Comment: oyyy i have sunglaces thats why :)

Comment: @StephLocke You could only have one `WHERE` clause per query. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html for the supported syntax.

Comment: I know, there was an edit to avoid code being `SELECT * FROM table WHERE  id = ? WHERE type <> 'tv' and code <> 123` which I originally highlighted by question.  @echo_Me has done two edits since - but they haven't shown the answer as edited on my screen

Answer (score 0):

```
select *  from tbl where id = 1 and (type <> "abc" or code <> "123");
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dc49/2

Comment: You achieved the same in different way :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample query for your problem.
If your table has coloum names as - type (VARCHAR or VARCHAR2 or CHAR) and code (VARCHAR or VARCHAR2 or CHAR)

`SELECT * FROM <table-name> WHERE type NOT IN ('tv') AND code NOT IN ('123')`;